# Don't understand this result of applying SplitBy in 11.3

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm using version 11.3.0.0

```
SplitBy[Tuples[{1, 2}, 3], First]
```

returns

```
{{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 2}}, 
 {{2, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 2}}}
```

Well and good. However,

```
SplitBy[Tuples[{1, 2}, 3], Last]
```

returns

```
{{{1, 1, 1}}, {{1, 1, 2}}, {{1, 2, 1}}, {{1, 2, 2}}, {{2, 1, 1}}, 
 {{2,1, 2}}, {{2, 2, 1}}, {{2, 2, 2}}}
```

Shouldn't it return

```
{{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1}}, 
 {{1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 2}, {2, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 2}}}
```

?

Thanks for any help with this.

Kerry Soileau

Comment: Replace `SplitBy` by `GatherBy` if you need the output you suggest

Answer (score 2):

This will be clearer if you only look at the elements being used by `SplitBy`. For your first example, this is what `SplitBy` is operating on

```
In[4]:= Tuples[{1, 2}, 3][[All, 1]]
(*Out[4]= {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2} *)
```

When `SplitBy` (or the equivalent `Split`) is run, it splits it into

```
In[5]:= Split[Tuples[{1, 2}, 3][[All, 1]]]
(*Out[5]= {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2}}*)
```

because it is looking at runs of equivalent values. So, when applied to the `Last` element

```
In[3]:= Tuples[{1, 2}, 3][[All, -1]]
(*Out[3]= {1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2}*)
```

you can see each run is only a single element in length. Therefor,

```
In[6]:= Split[Tuples[{1, 2}, 3][[All, -1]]]
(*Out[6]= {{1}, {2}, {1}, {2}, {1}, {2}, {1}, {2}}*)
```

If you want to collect similar elements, then [`GatherBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GatherBy.html) is the way to go, e.g.

```
In[7]:= GatherBy[Tuples[{1, 2}, 3], First]
(*Out[7]= {{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 2}}, 
         {{2, 1, 1}, {2,1, 2}, {2, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 2}}}*)

In[8]:= GatherBy[Tuples[{1, 2}, 3], Last]
(*Out[8]= {{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1}}, 
         {{1, 1, 2}, {1,2, 2}, {2, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 2}}}*)
```